# How to get gsub! to recognize different characters (uppercase, lowercase)

Tags: ruby, gsub

```
print "Enter your text here:"
user_text = gets.chomp
user_text_2 = user_text.gsub! "Damn", "Darn"
user_text_3 = user_text.gsub! "Shit", "Crap"
puts "Here is your edited text: #{user_text}"
```

I would like that code to also recognize when I use the lowercase versions of Shit and Damn and replace them with the substitute words. Right now it only recognizes when I type the words in with an uppercase first word. Is there any way to get it to recognize the lowercase words too, without adding more gsub! lines of code?

Comment: On a related note (in case you're planning to use this in a real app): http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a very short solution:

```
user_text.gsub!(/[Dd]amn/, 'Darn')
```

The more general approach, if this is what you want, is with an i which makes the regex case-insensitive.

```
user_text.gsub!(/damn/i, 'Darn')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the [`i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) flag on your patten to ignore case:

```
user_text_2 = user_text.gsub! /Damn/i, "Darn"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a Regexp and the `i` option, that makes the Regexp case insensitive:

```
foo = 'foo Foo'

foo.gsub(/foo/, 'bar')
#=> "bar Foo"
foo.gsub(/foo/i, 'bar')  # with i
#=> "bar bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions instead of strings. So `/damn/i` instead of `"damn".` The 'i' at the end of a regular expression means ignore casing.